# Binary expression tree node with two possible states

Tags: java, object-oriented, expression-trees

I am building out a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bina%E2%80%A6) and shown below is an implementation of the tree's node.

The node can be either a leaf or non-leaf, with leaves having `Integer` type values and non-leaves having `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands` type values. Leaves may have neither left nor right child nodes, and non-leaves must have both left and right child nodes.

I feel like this could be solved more appropriately using inheritance but can't seem to wrap my head around the generic `Object` member.

```
public class ExpressionTreeNode {

    private Object value;
    private ExpressionTreeNode leftNode;
    private ExpressionTreeNode rightNode;

    public ExpressionTreeNode(Object value) {
        this(value, null, null);
    }

    public ExpressionTreeNode(Object value, ExpressionTreeNode leftNode, ExpressionTreeNode rightNode) {

        if (value == null || (!(value instanceof Integer) && !(value instanceof ExpressionTreeNodeOperands))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument: value must be non-null with a type of Integer or ExpressionTreeNodeOperand");
        }

        if (leftNode == null && rightNode != null || leftNode != null && rightNode == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: leftNode and rightNode should both be null or non-null alike");
        }

        if ((value instanceof Integer) && (leftNode != null && rightNode != null)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: non-operand non-leaf node");
        }

        if (!(value instanceof Integer) && leftNode == null && rightNode == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: non-integer leaf node");
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    public boolean isLeafNode() {
        return (leftNode == null) && (rightNode == null);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public ExpressionTreeNode getLeftNode() {
        return leftNode;
    }

    public ExpressionTreeNode getRightNode() {
        return rightNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice post! And welcome to Code Review! We are glad we have a Sloth in the house. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect situation to introduce an interface. What you want to model is a tree-like structure, with nodes having a left and right subtree and leaf containing an integer value.

---

Your current code models this by having a single `ExpressionTreeNode` class, handling both cases of having a node with a left and right operand, and a leaf. What shows that this class has too much responsibility is the overhead you need to have to ensure its consistency:

```
if (value == null || (!(value instanceof Integer) && !(value instanceof ExpressionTreeNodeOperands))) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument: value must be non-null with a type of Integer or ExpressionTreeNodeOperand");
}

if (leftNode == null && rightNode != null || leftNode != null && rightNode == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: leftNode and rightNode should both be null or non-null alike");
}

if ((value instanceof Integer) && (leftNode != null && rightNode != null)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: non-operand non-leaf node");
}

if (!(value instanceof Integer) && leftNode == null && rightNode == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state: non-integer leaf node");
}
```

That is a lot of code to make sure that the node has a proper state after its construction. It also makes assumptions on the given arguments (namely, that you cannot pass a value that isn't an `Integer` or a `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands`): this is reasonable when well-documented but such constraints, if possible, would be preferable to ensure at compile-time.

For example, it will also compile if the caller gives an integer value along with a node, only to fail at run-time because it is incorrect.

---

The model you want to have here shows that, in fact, 3 classes need to be introduced:

- an `ExpressionTree` interface, that represents the tree-like structure.
- an `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands` class that would represent a node in the tree. A node would have 2 members: a left and a right subtree, represented as two members of type `ExpressionTree`.
- a `Leaf` class that would represent a leaf in the tree. This class would just have one member of type `int`.

A sample code would be the following:

```
interface ExpressionTree {
    boolean isLeaf();
}

class ExpressionTreeNodeOperands implements ExpressionTree {

    private ExpressionTree left;
    private ExpressionTree right;

    public ExpressionTreeNodeOperands(ExpressionTree left, ExpressionTree right) {
        this.left = Objects.requireNonNull(left);
        this.right = Objects.requireNonNull(right);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return false;
    }

}

class Leaf implements ExpressionTree {

    private int value;

    public Leaf(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Notice a couple of things:

- `Leaf` is now constructed directly with an `int` and you cannot construct it without one. Also, it is not a boxed `Integer`: `null` values were not permitted before and are simply not possible now.
- `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands` is constructed with two arguments: the left and right sub-tree, which could be another `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands`, or a `Leaf`. It also calls [`requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) to make sure that the given arguments are non-null.

The concern are now clearly separated: the node handles only its sub-trees, and the leaf handles only its value.

With this base, you can add convenience methods, like `isLeaf`, that would always return `false` for a node, and always return `true` for a leaf.

---

Then, depending on your actual usage, you may not even need a `getLeft()` and `getRight()` getters to retrieve the left and right node sub-trees. Let's take an example usage where we want to perform an infix traversal. You could add a `String infix();` method inside the interface `ExpressionTree`, that would return a `String` representation:

```
@Override
public String infix() {
    return "(" + left.infix() + "," + right.infix() + ")";
}
```

for a node, and

```
@Override
public String infix() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

for a leaf. And then you can have:

```
ExpressionTree tree = new ExpressionTreeNodeOperands(new ExpressionTreeNodeOperands(new Leaf(2), new Leaf(1)), new Leaf(3));
System.out.println(tree.infix()); // prints ((2,1),3)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, this is starting to make more sense. One thing that isn't addressed here is that the `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands` and `Leaf` classes both have values, `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands` has an enum value and `Leaf` has an int. Using the interface how can I implement getters for these values since they are of different types? Thanks again!

Comment: @SlothArmstrong I would argue that you probably don't need such getter: once the tree is built, what would the caller do with the value alone? It is used to perform an operation, which means the tree will delegate the operation to `Leaf` or `ExpressionTreeNodeOperands`. In any case, if you do want it, one possibility that I see is to parameterize the tree with `ExpressionTree<T>`, and add a `T value();` method.